Override files in Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\
In my local dev system I need to symlink modules into the /vendor folder. Unfortunately magento checks if any included file actually resides inside magento's root folder.
Files from outside that scope are not permitted for security reasons.
Since I only need this in my local dev setup I wanted to override classes inside Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ but that does not seem to work at all.
This is my etc/di.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\PathValidator" type="My\Module\Directory\PathValidatory" />
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\DenyListPathValidator" type="My\Module\Directory\DenyListPathValidator" />
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\CompositePathValidator" type="My\Module\Directory\CompositePathValidator" />
</config>

None of them make any difference.
Is there another way to override those files or even another way to disable this security check conditionally?
Thank you.

Btw... I also tried plugins to no avail.

If all else fails, try bind mount (on Linux) ?

Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.
